# Botão gerado dentro de retorno do $.ajax não funciona

Tags: php, jquery

preciso de um help aqui.

Então, estou usando `$.ajax` do **jQuery** para buscar dados no banco e prencher uma variavel php **$html** que vai trazer um conteúdo já pronto.

O **problema** é que nesse **conteúdo** eu tenho um **botão**

```
$html .= "

  <button id='btnRelatorio' class='button'>Gerar Relatório</button>

";
```

e tenho na página que vai receber esse `$.ajax` um **jquery** para esse **button**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

  $("#btnRelatorio").click ( function () {

    alert();

  });

});
```

Mas o `alert` não dispara.

Alguma idéia do porque?

**obs**.: `o class='button'` está funcionando corretamente mas o `js` não
Simplemente não acontece nada nem dá **erro** no **console**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para elementos gerados dinamicamente ele não encontra mesmo.

Você precisa fazer algo do tipo

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnRelatorio', function(){ 
     alert();
});
```